# Hide other images while running fancybox-thumb

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I want to hide a large number of images on the html page. While using fancybox-thumbnail to show there are other images to view. Goal is to have the page look clean and not cluttered with a bunch of images. But it's not working, not sure if it's something conflicting or does this idea not work and I HAVE to show the other images on the page.

HEAD Tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

<script>$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox-thumb").fancybox({
    prevEffect  : 'none',
    nextEffect  : 'none',
    helpers : {
        title   : {
            type: 'outside'
        },
        thumbs  : {
            width   : 50,
            height  : 50
        }
    }
});
});
</script>
```

BODY Tags:

```
<a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-thumb" href="images/art/3pk.jpg">
        <div class="imgconcept"></div></a>
<div class="hidden">
    <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-thumb" href="images/art/clcfashnb.jpg"><img src="images/art/clcfashnb.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want all images hidden right from the start? Your question seems to be unclear. fancybox-thumb runs when? When an image is clicked?

Comment: Not all images, I'll have one main image on the page. When you click that one image, it'll run fancybox-thumb to show there are other images. similar to what is here: http://jsfiddle.net/uZCC6/ but that doesn't even work :/

Comment: So when any image is clicked, the fancy box should appear and all images should be hidden? Then when the fancy box disappears all the images reappear?

Comment: hmmm...the sample on jsfiddle didn't save. I'm having an off day, lets try this again. The sample I'm trying to do is this: https://jsfiddle.net/Punkie/h10qb505/embedded/result/
I want one image shown, click on that one image and it should run fancybox, but with thumbs on the bottom. It's not working.

Comment: You're getting an error on that link: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" Make sure jquery has been added.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Punkie/h10qb505/4/ I've added the jquery in frameworks & extensions. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

<script>$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox-thumb").fancybox({
    prevEffect  : 'none',
    nextEffect  : 'none',
    helpers : {
        title   : {
            type: 'outside'
        },
        thumbs  : {
            width   : 50,
            height  : 50
        }
    }
});
});
</script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/h10qb505/16/)

The problem was actually straight forward. You were missing two vital libraries for the thumbnails to work.

[jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js)

[jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css)

That's all there was to it.

Your code was good.

```
$(".fancybox-thumb").fancybox({
        prevEffect: 'none',
        nextEffect: 'none',
        helpers: {
            title: {
                type: 'outside'
            },
            thumbs: {
                width: 50,
                height: 50
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, but what you have is similar to the multiple galleries listed in Fancybox Tips & Tricks. It still doesn't have the thumbnails of the other images on the bottom of the full-size image when it runs. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: This is what Fancybox shows for their multiple galleries:
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful

#9 shows their multiple galleries, but no thumbnail

Comment: Nevermind, I understand what you mean. I'll look into it

Comment: I do have those links in the <head> to call up those (2) libraries and the path is correct. But it doesn't work when I add the class "hidden" in the html so those images don't show up on the page. I just want the other images shown in fancybox.

Comment: And the jsfiddle I linked does not do this?

Comment: Ah man, yours work. I did the exact same in my html/css and it doesn't work for mine. I don't get it. I know the path to those two files that you say is missing is correctly set. Do I need to add the .hidden tag in fancybox's css and not my styles?

Comment: You'll notice in my external links I have 4 files. Do you have all those 4? You can keep .hidden tag on that div container you created.

Comment: For mine, everything I'm doing right now is done locally on my laptop because I don't want this live till I get everything working. All the images/library paths are correctly set, but that shouldn't matter does it? When I use regular, multiple galleries "fancybox" with nothing hidden and no thumbs, it works fine .

Comment: Post all the errors you get in your console log. If you don't have any let me know as well.

Comment: Console says:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefinedjquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7:22 (anonymous function)jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7:162 (anonymous function)

Comment: Will be hard reading all of it in the comments. Update your question. Post the same errors. Also show part of your html where you link all the libraries related to fancybox (js and css) (I'm interested in the order on how you linked them and where you create your .fancybox)

Comment: @punkie You're missing two links. I added them in the post above.

Comment: YOU ROCK Grimbode! How could I have missed those two. It finally works. Doh!

Comment: :3 It happens. Good luck with the project. If you need help feel free to send me a message on twitter.com/grimbode